# JQuery .ajax with async=true always returns error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I try to make a jQuery.ajax call:

```
jQuery("#search_form").live("submit", function() {
    search_nr = jQuery("#search_input").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/modules/mod_findarticle/process.php',
        data: "search_nr="+search_nr,
        async: true,
        'success':  function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
        'error': function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(jqXHR.status+",  " + jqXHR.statusText+",  "+textStatus+",  "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

In return i always get an alert with **"0, error, error,"** message. Everything's fine with **async=false**.
I know that with asynchronous call the script finish work before any actual data is recieved but what can be done to avoid this?

Comment: If you inspect the response in Firebug, what is the error code returned?

Comment: Why are you even setting it? It is true by default.

Comment: Not related to the error, but `.live` is deprecated. You should use `.on`.

Comment: What kind of data is the PHP returning? Is it setting the Content-type correctly?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. So:
1. the error messages are displayed by `alert(jqXHR.status+",  " + jqXHR.statusText+",  "+textStatus+",  "+errorThrown);` which shows **0, error, error,**
2. Indeed, async is enanled by default. If I remove **async=true** at all, nothing changes.
3. thanks for the comment, but i doubt that the problem is related to .live()
4. I tried to add the dataType parameter to the .ajax call, setting it to "html" or "json" with no effect.

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of keywords in your ajax call.

Change `'success':` to `success:` and `'error':` to `error:`.

Comment: Changing strings to keywords (success & error) does not help.

Comment: Can you replace `function() {` with `function(e) { e.preventDefault();` - perhaps something is being submitted twice? Can you check the network tab in Firebug on Firefox or in Developer Tools on Chrome to see what is being passed as data?

Comment: Yes, it worked! It appears that I simply submitted the data twice by triggering 'submit' event on the form! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to user ***mccannf*** :
The data was submitted twice by triggering the 'submit' event on the form, so the script always stopped processing data before the second call. Replacing `function()` in `.live(...)` with `function(e) {e.preventDefault; ... }` disables the default submit action and hence does the trick!